# Redirect according to the URL

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

I have the following scenario:
I'd like to do a redirection system like this:

```
/redirect/place1   ->  /page.php?place=place1
/redirect/testabc  ->  /page.php?place=testabc
/redirect/xyzw123  ->  /page.php?place=xyzw123
```

The only way I can see now is to do subfolders in /redirect which have a index.php who redirects it. But I'd like that to be fully automatic.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Apache server?  A 301 redirect in .htaccess file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect /redirect/(Anything) to /page.php?place=(Same as Anything)

You can use redirect command from [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
Redirect 301 /redirect/ /page.php?place=
```

or

you wan use the RewriteRule comand from [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteRule /redirect/(.*) /page.php?place=$1 [L]
```

More informations:

- [L] is the kind of redirect, you can add a status code if you want to do a redirect condition, like [L,R=301] will redirect sending 301 redirect permanent
- here you can find all http code for the redirection
  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_codes_HTTP
- here you can find all the flags from the rewrite condition
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
- If you want to redirect only if page or folder doesn't exist:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
  RewriteRule /redirect/(.*) /page.php?place=$1 [L]
  ```

`!-d` mean not found as a folder

`!-f` mean not found as a file